# Traversing a table column -jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-traversing

Given a 3 by 3 table, i want to add a class to all  the cells of 3rd column .

I have tried doing

```
$( 'td:eq(3)' ).addclass('special');
$( 'td:eq(5)' ).addclass('special');
$( 'td:eq(8)' ).addclass('special');
```

but the problem is writing 3 lines of code. Can a single line of code  do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("td:nth-child(3)").addClass('special');
```

good article about nth-child -

http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/

Comment: I should have left the `tr > ` part off of my answer since it really isn't necessary. +1

Answer (score 7):

```
$('tr > td:nth-child(3)').addClass('special');
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/TcQex/

***DOCS:*** http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector